# Android Keep a process run in background

Tags: android, android-intent

I know we can use `Services` and `IntentServices`, But I have requirement that a class keeps running and never gets removed but garbage collector.
To describe more of the reason : I'm using an event system.
So when an activity or service fires an event the central event class catches that event and does whatever needed.
How can I create a class to accomplish this task? I know the class which extends `Application` and added to manifest is one way.
But I'm looking for a better way.

Comment: Implement a `BroadCastReceiver` to perform this task .

Comment: Thanks for downvotes for legitimate questions, seriously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I have requirement that a class keeps running and never gets removed but garbage collector.

If you ask about "class" in general, you can use a `static` variable. It will never be garbage collected unless you assign `null` to it because a class object will hold a strong reference to it.

> So when an activity or service fires an event the central event class catches that event and does whatever needed.

Use a `BroadcastReceiver` component for this. It was designed exactly for this purpose.

I don't see how your first question is related to the second one though.. I suppose you want your receiver to always handle events. So in this case just register it in `AndroidManifest.xml` so that it will run every time event occurs.

Comment: I'm using EventBus already, no need for ``BroadCastReceiver``. My question is If I create a class named ``EventHandler`` and add a static variable to a class which extends ``Application`` that class will never be garbage collected?

Comment: Correct. It will be garbage collected only when the app process is killed completely.

Comment: tnx, the exact answer Im looking for.

Comment: @Mehrdad see `android.app.Application` docs: "There is normally no need to subclass Application. In most situation, static singletons can provide the same functionality in a more modular way."

Comment: @pskink  would you please a more detail explanation how to achieve without using ``android.app.Application``?